# Thinking of Error Boundary in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still not clear why we need Error Boundary in React. In my opinion, the concept of Error Boundary came up in component based React development. Actually in many tech interviews, a number of CTOs ask me about the Error Boundary. I managed to answer but I often knock myself out how to implement Error Boundary in React hooks. Actually lots of lifecycle methods are deprecated and I want to know how to solve this out.

Comment: I think the documentation states why quite clearly: *"In the past, JavaScript errors inside components used to corrupt React’s internal state and cause it to emit cryptic errors on next renders. These errors were always caused by an earlier error in the application code, but React did not provide a way to handle them gracefully in components, and could not recover from them."*

Comment: As far as I'm aware error boundaries are still only supported in class components. *Actually lots of lifecycle methods are deprecated* - I don't think this is true, only a couple are deprecated.